# My cron jobs runs several times

Tags: linux, cron

On my server i have three cron jobs:

by typing `crontab -e` i get the following:

```
0 */24 * * * wget -qO /dev/null http://www.example.com/Users/mailNotify?token=1234 >> /var/log/cronLog.txt
0 */23 * * * sh /var/www/backup/backupScript
0 */23 * * * wget -qO /dev/null http://www.example.com/Users/off_score?token=1234 >> /var/log/cronLog.txt
```

These cronjobs runs twice:

at 00.00 and at 01.00 every night.

The funny thing about this is that it runs all three jobs at each of the above hour.

Can anyone tell me what i have done wrong when creating these?

Comment: You want them to run at 23.00 and 0.00 once?

Comment: I want them to only run at 00.00 or any other defined hour. but the issue is that it is running all of the commands at both hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your cronjobs running once at a specific time, you shouldn't use `*/` as this will make your cronjobs run every 23 hours, which causes the behaviour of running at 1 and then again, 23 hours later, at 0, as cron is calculating when to run to run every 23 hours during one day.

To run all of them at midnight like you commented, use cron like this:

```
0 0 * * * wget -qO /dev/null http://www.example.com/Users/mailNotify?token=1234 >> /var/log/cronLog.txt
0 0 * * * sh /var/www/backup/backupScript
0 0 * * * wget -qO /dev/null http://www.example.com/Users/off_score?token=1234 >> /var/log/cronLog.txt
```

Cron definitions:

```
# * * * * *  command to execute
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 # │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

You are telling cron to run every day with the 3rd `*` in the command.

Comment: With this will the run every day?

Comment: Every day at 0.00, yes. To make one or more of them run at 23.00 (11pm), simply change the second zero to 23. @MarcRasmussen